# Forçar angular a reanalizar o ngClass quando a largura da tela mudar

Tags: angularjs

Estou construindo uma aplicação onde dependo do ngClass para mudar a classe de elementos. O problema é que não estou conseguindo fazer com o ngClass interprete uma mudança na largura da tela (conceito de responsividade).

Sei que consigo fazer isso utilizando o `$scope.$watch`em outra diretiva mas pretendo manter o máximo de controle já nativo no AngularJS. Existe alguma forma de fazer com que o ngClass identifique que houve uma mudança na largura da página e reavalie sua condição?

Answer (score 4):

Você pode definir a seguinte função dentro do `.run`

```
.run(function($window, $timeout, $rootScope) {
    var timer;

    function verificaTela() {
        var width = $window.innerWidth;

        if(width < 600) {
            $rootScope._isMobile = true;
        } else {
            $rootScope._isMobile = false;
        }
    }

    //Chama a função quando mudar o tamanho da tela
    angular.element($window).on('resize', function() {
        $timeout.cancel(timer);
        timer = $timeout(verificaTela, 600);
    })

    //Chama a função no primeiro load
    verificaTela();
});
```

Eu prefiro declarar dentro do `.run` pois ela é executada logo no inicio da aplicação, portanto, quando seu DOM começar a ser estruturado, o valor já estará disponível.

Depois basta fazer as verificações com `ngClass`, por exemplo:

```
<div ng-class="{'classeMobile': _isMobile}"></div>

//ou assim
<div ng-class="_isMobile ? 'classeMobile' : 'classeDesktop'"></div>
```

Comment: mas assim você está verificando em uma aplicação que verifica ao carregar e não em uma mudança de tela repentina. imagine que em algum momento seu usuário modigica o navegador, deixando o mesmo em meia tela. dessa forma, ainda assim não funciona

Comment: além disso, fazendo através do run, voce sai do escopo de eventos a partir de ações, portanto não dá pra testar isso em um usuário real

Comment: @LeandroLUK `angular.element($window).on('resize', function() {` Isso aqui faz a verificação quando o usuário mudar a tela do browser. Eu utilizo no `.run` pois também preciso saber o tamanho da tela no estado inicial. Posteriormente, se o usuário mudar a dimensão do navegador, ele vai continuar sendo analisado. Além disso, eu criei uma verificação de timer para executar a função somente 600ms após o usuário finalizar o redimensionamento, ao invés de executar a cada px que ele altera. A lógica de verificação usei true ou false, mas você pode usar outras

Comment: entendo que dessa forma eu estaria saindo do escopo da função ngClass. além disso, por convenção o que procuro deve-se ser trabalhado através de uma diretiva para  melhorar a escalabilidade. Na forma que você pensou funciona, mas não é escalável. estou procurando pro algo que o angular 1 já tenha, mas pelo que vi realmente sou obrigado a gerar uma nova diretiva.

Comment: O princípio é o mesmo, basta você migrar a função de `element($window).on('resize');` para a diretiva e usar a mesma. Como dito, usar no run é uma preferência, mas você pode usar tranquilamente no directive